# Do full-outer-join with pandas.merge_asof

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, outer-join

Hi I need to align some time series data with nearest timestamps, so I think `pandas.merge_asof` could be a good candidate. However, it does not have an option to set `how='outer'` like in the standard `merge` method.

An example can be:

df1:

```
                                   Value1
Time
2020-07-17 14:25:03.535906075      108
2020-07-17 14:25:05.457247019      110
2020-07-17 14:25:07.467777014      126
```

df2:

```
                                  Value2
Time
2020-07-17 14:25:03.535018921     222
2020-07-17 14:25:04.545104980     150
2020-07-17 14:25:07.476825953      60
```

Then for example, do this `merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('0.3s'))
```

The results will be:

```
                               Value1  Value2
Time
2020-07-17 14:25:03.535906075     108   222.0
2020-07-17 14:25:05.457247019     110     NaN
2020-07-17 14:25:07.467777014     126    60.0
```

But what I want is:

```
                               Value1  Value2
Time
2020-07-17 14:25:03.535906075     108   222.0
2020-07-17 14:25:04.545104980     NaN   150.0   <---- this is the difference
2020-07-17 14:25:05.457247019     110     NaN
2020-07-17 14:25:07.467777014     126    60.0
```

basically like a full outer join.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So this is the case with 2 dataframes. What if, say for example, there are 10 dataframes (i.e. `df1, df2, ..., df10`) need to do this "nearest" merging, what will be a good way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems simple enough yet no direct solution. There's an option to merge again to bring in the missing rows:

```
# enumerate the rows of `df2` to later identify which are missing
df2 = df2.reset_index().assign(idx=np.arange(df2.shape[0]))
(pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index(), 
               df2[['Time','idx']], 
              on='Time',
              direction='nearest', 
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('0.3s'))
  .merge(df2, on='idx', how='outer')                        # merge back on row number
  .assign(Time=lambda x: x['Time_x'].fillna(x['Time_y']))   # fill the time
  .set_index(['Time'])                                      # set index back
  .drop(['Time_x','Time_y','idx'], axis=1)
  .sort_index()
)

                               Value1  Value2
Time                                         
2020-07-17 14:25:03.535906075   108.0   222.0
2020-07-17 14:25:04.545104980     NaN   150.0
2020-07-17 14:25:05.457247019   110.0     NaN
2020-07-17 14:25:07.467777014   126.0    60.0
```

Comment: Hi thanks! What do you think could be a good way to merge more than 2 dataframes? Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 3):

1. Unfortunately, there is no `how` parameter in `pd.merge_asof` like there is with `pd.merge`, otherwise you could simply pass `how='outer'`.
2. As a workaround, you can `append` the unmatched values from the other dataframe manually
3. Then, sort the index with `.sort_index()`

---

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('0.3s'))
df4 = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('0.3s'))
df5 = df3.append(df4[df4['Value1'].isnull()]).sort_index()
df5
Out[1]: 
                               Value1  Value2
Time                                         
2020-07-17 14:25:03.535906075   108.0   222.0
2020-07-17 14:25:04.545104980     NaN   150.0
2020-07-17 14:25:05.457247019   110.0     NaN
2020-07-17 14:25:07.467777014   126.0    60.0
```

Comment: Hi thanks! What do you think could be a good way to merge more than 2 dataframes? Please see the updated question.

Comment: @circle999 That requires a different solution. Can you create a new question and reference back to this question? YOu can copy and paste all of your data, and add multiple example dataframes (like 3 instead of 2). It's generally frowned upon to update the question like this.