# Do full-outer-join with pandas.merge_asof on more than 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

My question is an update of the following question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64723478/do-full-outer-join-with-pandas-merge-asof), I have the same problem but I need to merge more than 2 dataframes based on the nearest timestamp.
I tried different methods but I wasn't able to find the solution yet. Thanks.

df1

| time | Value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:03.535906075 | 108 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:05.457247019 | 110 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:07.467777014 | 126 |

df2

| time | Value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:03.535018921 | 222 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:04.545104980 | 150 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:07.476825953 | 60 |

df3

| time | Value3 |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:03.535018921 | 47 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:04.545104980 | 60 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:08.476825953 | 120 |

Expected result

| time | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:03.535018921 | 108 | 220 | 47 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:04.545104980 | Nan | 150 | 60 |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:07.476825953 | 110 | NaN | NAN |
| 2020-07-17 14:25:07.476825953 | 126 | 60 | 120 |

I found this method in the previous question but I don't know how to apply to more than 2 dataframes:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('0.3s'))
df4 = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('0.3s'))
df5 = df3.append(df4[df4['Value1'].isnull()]).sort_index()
```

Comment: you should provide a complete minimal example

Comment: The expected result is what you showed in 'result'?